# Python - Best search method for finding entries in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, algorithm, search

What is the best search method for finding entries in a dataframe based on their column values. My dataframe is formatted like this:

```
| header a | header b | header c | header d | header e |
|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|    1     |    1     |     1    |    1     |     1    |
|    3     |    2     |     5    |    6     |     2    |
|    2     |    2     |     2    |    2     |     2    |
```

There are hundreds of unsorted rows and I am looking for the row with values [3,2,5,6,2]. The brute force approach would be to check if the first column contains the value 3. If so, check if the second column contains the value 2, etc.
Is there a more optimized approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mask it is checked for equality with the searched list. The indexes are then stored in the list generator,
where all values matched. The print outputs the found lines.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'header a':[1,3,2,2],'header b':[1,2,2,3],'header c':[1,5,2,5],
                   'header d':[1,6,2,6],'header e':[1,2,2,2]})


mask = df.values == [3,2,5,6,2]
result = [i for i in range(0, len(mask)) if mask[i].all() == True]

print(df.loc[result,:])
```

Output

```
   header a  header b  header c  header d  header e
1         3         2         5         6         2
```